# Firebase get error when data is null from database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        name = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
        String myUrl = snapshot.child("photoURL").getValue().toString();
        txtFullName.setText(name);
        txtWelcome.setText("Hoşgeldin " + name);

        if(myUrl.isEmpty()) {
            changePhotoWithName(name);
        }
        else {
            changePhoto(myUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Here my code, with FirebaseRef listennig database and retrive data , but the problem is that sametimes my data is null and getting error.

Comment: What error? Please use a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                name = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                String myUrl = snapshot.child("photoURL").getValue().toString();
                txtFullName.setText(name);
                txtWelcome.setText("Hoşgeldin " + name);

                if(myUrl.isEmpty()){
                    changePhotoWithName(name);
                }
                else {
                    changePhoto(myUrl);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    if(myUrl.length()>0){
      if(myUrl.isEmpty()){
          changePhotoWithName(name);
       }
        else {
            changePhoto(myUrl);
        }
   }
```